# Adding Commas And Quotes After Each Element of String List

Tags: php, explode, implode

I have a list like this :

```
$list = 
"6/17/2017 21:17
6/17/2017 21:14
6/17/2017 21:11
6/17/2017 21:05
6/17/2017 21:03
6/17/2017 20:59
6/17/2017 20:36
6/17/2017 20:35
6/17/2017 20:33";
```

I need to convert that list into an array. How can I do this? I have way too many elements to do this manually.

Result

```
$list = array("datetime","datetime");
```

Comment: You want `array(array("datetime","datetime"), ...);`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I just want the $list to be converted into a normal one dimensional array...

Comment: you cant have multiple items with the same key

Comment: Perhaps you could help us by giving an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the items are separated by new line you can do something like this:

```
$items = explode(PHP_EOL, $list);
```

Please be aware that these constants are defined by the PHP core. It might not work when you change systems. Read more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Best option to cover all cases use this:

```
$items = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $list);
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. How do I use this?

Comment: @Clark What do you mean? Use any of the examples above and do a `print_r($items)` or `var_dump($items)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

You can split your string by newline using `preg_split`.  It looks as though you want to do some date time formatting, so here's an example of then converting that array's items into date time objects, that you then can format the output as you choose.

```
$list = 
"6/17/2017 21:17
6/17/2017 21:14
6/17/2017 21:11
6/17/2017 21:05
6/17/2017 21:03
6/17/2017 20:59
6/17/2017 20:36
6/17/2017 20:35
6/17/2017 20:33";

$a_list = preg_split('/\R/', $list);

foreach($a_list as $str_date)
    $datetime_list[] = new dateTime($str_date);

foreach($datetime_list as $dateTime)
    echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d 'H:i:s', \n");
```

Output:

```
2017-06-17 '21:17:00', 
2017-06-17 '21:14:00', 
2017-06-17 '21:11:00', 
2017-06-17 '21:05:00', 
2017-06-17 '21:03:00', 
2017-06-17 '20:59:00', 
2017-06-17 '20:36:00', 
2017-06-17 '20:35:00', 
2017-06-17 '20:33:00',
```